# How to read informats data: $1,000.1M to 1000.1

Tags: sas, informat

The datasets include a list of numbers:

```
    $1,000.1M
      $100.5M
    $1,002.3M
     $23.4M
     $120.3M
```

I want to read the variable as a numeric in SAS

the result should be:

```
   Money(millions)
   1000.1
   100.5
   1002.3
   23.4
   120.3
```

I used COMMAw.d to read this data, but cannot run

The code is:

```
    input Money(millions) COMMA9.1;
    run;
```

How to modify it?

Thank you very much！

Comment: Are all numbers millions? Or is it possible to have a B or to have numbers that are not in the millions?

Comment: Yes, all are millions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [COMMA](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000204404.htm) informat does not expect letters like 'M', it removes only commas, blanks, dollar signs, percent signs, dashes, and close parentheses. 
You can just convert your raw string to a string containing a number by removing all characters you do not need:

```
data input;
    length moneyRaw $200;    
    infile datalines;
    input moneyRaw $;

    datalines;
$1,000.1M
$100.5M
$1,002.3M
$23.4M
$120.3M
;
run;

data result;
    set input;
   * "k" modifier inverts the removed characters;
    money = input(compress(moneyRaw,"0123456789.","k"),best.);
run;
```

Or if you know regex, you can add some intrigue to the code for anyone who reads it in the future:

```
data resultPrx;
    set input;
    moneyUpdated = prxChange("s/^\$(\d+(,\d+)*(\.\d+)?)M$/$1/",1,strip(moneyRaw));
    money = input(compress(moneyUpdated,','),best.);
run;
```

Comment: I didn't know the compress function before, this is my first time to study SAS. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I think you're best off reading it as a character and then processing it as in Dmitry's answer. But if it was a single column you could read it if you set the delimiter to M. I suspect this will work in a demo, but not in your full process.

```
data input;
    informat moneyRaw dollar8.;    
    infile datalines dlm='M';
    input moneyRaw ;
    *moneyRaw = moneyRaw * (1000000);
    format moneyRaw dollar32.;
    datalines;
$1,000.1M
$100.5M
$1,002.3M
$23.4M
$120.3M
;
run;
```

Comment: Thank you! So is there no way to directly read this data as a numeric?